# PyBluez does not detect the built-in bluetooth adapter

Tags: python, bluetooth

I want to start developing some tools that let me communicate between my phone and computer via bluetooth, and I want to use Python for it. I installed the python bluetooth module (PyBluez), but it does not detect my built in BT adapter (I'm on a Toshiba Satellite A300).

```
import bluetooth
nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()

print(nearby_devices)
```

returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/bt.py", line 3, in <module>
    nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 9, in discover_devices
    return bt.discover_devices (flush_cache, lookup_names)
IOError: No Bluetooth adapter detected
```

Any help?

Comment: Yeah, definitely turned on, I can transfer files to and from my laptop and the phone via Toshiba's own BT stack.

Comment: I get the same error you posted, but only if no devices are discoverable. When there is a device to discover it works and I don't get the error.

Answer (score 2):

PyBluez uses MS Bluetooth driver stack and Widcom for Windows, for Linux it uses BlueZ. If your laptop has a different stack it is normal not to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could uninstall the driver (if it is possible), then restart Windows and let it install the default drivers. 
If you manage it, PyBluez will work better.